# linux diff: is there a way to list differences by when the files were last modified?

Tags: linux, date-time, terminal, diff

In the Linux terminal, I'm using

```
diff --recursive --brief dir1 dir2
```

A couple of weeks ago, dir1 and dir2 were identical, but they have both been modified since then. I would like to order to outputs by the date of the last modification for the files in dir2 (or dir1, or whichever is more recent, or the time at which they began to differ).

I looked at the diff options and there doesn't seem to be a built in way to do any of these.

Does anyone know a way?

Comment: maybe if you use find, then sort, then xargs?

Comment: I think it's time to put those directories under version control. (See: git)

Answer (score 1):

No, of all diff options, there isn't a built in way to do any of the things your required. You have to coin your own solution.

This would be a fairly simple and straightforward solution to start with:

```
find /path/to/dir1  /path/to/dir2 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM %p\n" | sort -r
```

what it gives you is a list of files in reverse-chronological order.

1. All the files that is newer than that a couple of weeks ago when `dir1` and `dir2` were identical are modified.
2. The modified file that comes on the top of the list is modified more recently. E.g., if `fileN` in `dir1` shows up higher than `dir2`, then `fileN` in `dir1` is newer.

Is this good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638761/456983) from Unix & Linux Stack Exchange
with a script that does exactly what you ask:

Simply call it like this:

```
<caller_shell> '/path/to/script.sh' dir1 dir2
```

Comment: Sorry, this is effectively a link-only answer. The better way to present it here would be to copy the script to this answer and leave the link to the other answer so the original poster can see additional details.